# Divergence of a first Piola-Kirchoff stress appearing in elasticity

Tags: multivariable-calculus, mathematical-physics, tensors, divergence-operator

I'm studying elasticity theory and for the problem "Finite Bending of an incompressible elastic block" I have the following first Piola-Kirchoff stress tensor:

$$S=\left(\frac{\pi + \mu_0}{\lambda_1} + \mu_0 \lambda_1\!\right)e_r \otimes e_1 + \left(\frac{\pi + \mu_0}{\lambda_2} + \mu_0 \lambda_2\!\right) e_\theta \otimes e_2$$

where $e_r = cos(\theta) e_1 + \sin(\theta) e_2$ and $e_\theta = - \sin(\theta) e_1 + \cos(\theta) e_2$

The author writes ([see here at page 186 formula (5.95)](https://books.google.it/books?id=f3RrYLujw8oC&pg=PA179&lpg=PA179&dq=Finite%20bending%20of%20an%20incompressible%20elastic%20block&source=bl&ots=hDKzQSjxSv&sig=ACfU3U3fLyBQ9a3XuAl14bfvVHTrmfKs6Q&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi61bzqxLfwAhVGi6QKHcWEBt8Q6AEwCXoECAUQAw#v=onepage&q=Finite%20bending%20of%20an%20incompressible%20elastic%20block&f=false)):

$$Div(S) = \frac{\partial }{\partial x_1^0} S_{r1} e_r + \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2^0} S_{\theta 2} e_{\theta} = 0$$

but **I can't understand what are the steps to get this result**.

I mean, I know that in cartesian coordinates the divergence of a tensor $S$ is defined as $(Div(S))_i = S_{ij,j}$ but I don't know why he wrote that expression with $e_r$ and $e_\theta$. How can I compute that divergence? What are the steps I have to do?